# Sprague Vitamin Q High Voltage (25 kV) Power Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, mains, industrial

Might any of you know more details about these high voltage capacitors? Specifically:

1. What are they used for?
2. How are they constructed? (e.g. glass-sealed paper in oil)
3. Are they of value, and if so, to whom?
4. Am I correct that the labeling implies 2F and 25,000 volts?

My father recently passed away, and I would like to sell these two units. He has an array of incredible equipment and parts, much of which I'm keeping (we built a Tesla coil together, a bank of smaller caps used to vaporize thin copper wire....an old science project when I was in 8th grade, etc), but I'm having a hard time finding out more about these units.

My intuition is that they are intended for power/utility use, perhaps for reactive power compensation, but that's really outside my area of understanding.

Also, I am aware of how dangerous these units are - they are always stored with a short wire across the terminals.

Grateful for any insight from folks.

[image: Photo of two capacitors]

[image: Close up of label on capacitor]

Comment: wow  ... looks like a great steampunk prop

Comment: 2 microfarads probably, definitely not farads. The last time I saw capacitors in this sort of range was on TV News, when somebody got in big trouble selling a bunch of them to Saddam Hussein. If you have a few dozen, Kim Jong-Un might take them.

Comment: https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1990-09-01-me-68-story.html

Comment: Ha! That's pretty funny. Appreciate the heads up on microfarads (my error).